# Make specific elements of numpy matrix as 0

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have got index of 0 elements of Numpy Matrix (M) using:

```
index_array = numpy.argwhere(M == 0)
```

Now, I want to make these index elements (index present in index_array)  as 0 in other matrix B. Is there any numpy way to do this?

For eg : index_array contains

```
[[2 1]
[4 4]]
```

, so make element present at (2,1) and (4,4) in Matrix B as 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have used `np.where` which returns a tuple of row and col index and thus can be used as indexing directly, instead of `argwhere`, so long as the index is not out of bound for `B`, you can do:

```
B[np.where(M == 0)] = 0
```

*Example*:

```
M = np.array([[1,2],[3,0],[0,1]])

M
#array([[1, 2],
#       [3, 0],
#       [0, 1]])

B = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])    
B
#array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [4, 5, 6],
#       [7, 8, 9]])

B[np.where(M == 0)] = 0

B
#array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [4, 0, 6],
#       [0, 8, 9]])
```

If you want to stick to `np.argwhere`, you can get the row index and col index respectively and then do the assignment:

```
index_array = np.argwhere(M == 0)
B[index_array[:,0], index_array[:,1]] = 0
```

Comment: Or better yet, just use `B[M == 0] = 0`

Comment: More generally, you can use `B[tuple(index_array.T)]` to index with the result of `np.argwhere`

Comment: @Eric Good option. Didn't know tuple can work on an array like that.

Comment: `a[b,c]` is just syntactic sugar for `a[(b, c)]`. In both cases, they invoke `type(a).__getitem__(a, (b, c))`